# No parameterless constructor Upload Image

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I understand program need only this WrappedJsonResult2 UploadImageSmall() without parameter but I send parameter in UploadImage.

I change this code because I would like to have two UploadImage in one View and everywhere I gave 2 to change id and maybe I made somewhere mistake (in Upload Image part) but really I don`t know where can be problem with this.

[tutorial for one Upload Image](http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2011/11/16/AJAX-File-Uploads-with-jQuery-and-MVC-3.aspx)

Error

```
    No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

    Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

    Source Error:
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +199
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +572
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +449
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +317
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +117
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
```

Upload Image

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImageSmall", "StronaGlowna", FormMethod.Post,
                                         new
                                             {
                                                 enctype = "multipart/form-data",
                                                 id = "ImgForm2",
                                                 name = "ImgForm2",
                                                 target = "UploadTarget"
                                             }))
{
    <input type="file" name="imageFile2" />

    <input type="button" value="Zapisz" onclick="UploadImage2()" />
}
<iframe id="UploadTarget2" name="UploadTarget2" onload="UploadImage_Complete2();" style="position: absolute;
    left: -999em; top: -999em;"></iframe>
<div id="Images2">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isFirstLoad2 = true;

    function UploadImage2() {
        $("#ImgForm2").submit();
    }
    function UploadImage_Complete2() {
        //Check to see if this is the first load of the iFrame
        if (isFirstLoad2 == true) {
            isFirstLoad2 = false;
            return;
        }

        //Reset the image form so the file won't get uploaded again
        document.getElementById("ImgForm2").reset();

        //Grab the content of the textarea we named jsonResult .  This shold be loaded into
        //the hidden iFrame.
        var newImg2 = $.parseJSON($("#UploadTarget2").contents().find("#jsonResult2")[0].innerHTML);

        //If there was an error, display it to the user
        if (newImg2.IsValid == false) {
            alert(newImg2.Message);
            return;
        }

        //Create a new image and insert it into the Images div.  Just to be fancy,
        //we're going to use a "FadeIn" effect from jQuery
        var imgDiv2 = document.getElementById("Images2");
        var img2 = new Image();
        img2.src = newImg2.ImagePath;

        //Hide the image before adding to the DOM
        $(img2).hide();
        imgDiv2.appendChild(img2);
        //Now fade the image in
        $(img2).fadeIn(500, null);
    }
</script>
```

JSON

```
[HttpPost]
        public WrappedJsonResult2 UploadImageSmall(HttpPostedFileWrapper imageFile)
        {

            if (imageFile == null || imageFile.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                return new WrappedJsonResult2
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        IsValid = false,
                        Message = "No file was uploaded.",
                        ImagePath = string.Empty
                    }
                };
            }

            var fileName = String.Format("{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/UserImages")), fileName);

            imageFile.SaveAs(imagePath);

            var model = new StronaGlowna();
            if (!TryUpdateModel(model))
            {
            }
            model.MaleZdjecie = String.Format("~/Content/UserImages/{0}", fileName);

            return new WrappedJsonResult2
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    IsValid = true,
                    Message = string.Empty,
                    ImagePath = Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/UserImages/{0}", fileName))
                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here was problem -> public **WrappedJsonResult2 UploadImageSmall(HttpPostedFileWrapper imageFile2)** I forgot change imageFile name because in JSON event have to got this same parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using partial Views. some link below:

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/638_Understanding_Partial_Views_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Application.aspx

http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

Hope its what you want.

Comment: I would like to know why JSON send information to Method UploadImageSmall without parameter. I know how use partial View and believe me this will not help because I will have two similar id in two Views and will be problem with JS.